Is it better to use the definite or the indefinite article?
I've recently been thinking about the best way to apply definite and indefinite articles to certain noun phrases, specifically those that contain prepositions. See the following two examples, in which the POV character, Jake, is seeing all these things for the first time:

[1] Jake entered the room. Sunlight entered through gaps in a boarded-up window.


[2] Jake entered the room. Sunlight entered through the gaps in a boarded-up window.

In the first example, I have chosen to forgo the use of 'the,' making 'gaps' indefinite. This is because the reader is encountering these gaps for the first time, and it is feasible that a boarded-up window, if constructed with precision, may not have any obvious gaps.
The second example assumes knowledge on the reader's part, presenting 'the gaps' as something that would obviously be there. A similar example could be the handle of a door; we're unlikely to write, 'He grabbed a handle of a door.'
In your opinion, what is the better option here (and in similar cases)? And why?

I think you have answered your own question, at least in this particular sentence.
fwiw, I agree with your choice, but it's an opinion not a rule.

Please say how the Question belongs here in SE Writing, rather than somewhere such as English Language Learners?

@Robbie Goodwin, because the question pertains to the nuanced meanings of language in a situation where the answer is largely subjective. There’s no confusion around how these articles are used, so it doesn’t require someone to be a learner to ask this question.

The point is indeed that the question pertains to the nuanced meanings of language in a situation where the answer is largely subjective
Confusion here includes how your one article is used, and how using no article might make 'gaps' indefinite.
I suggest asking that Question shows sufficient lack of confidence to move the topic out of Writing.
I also think any detailed Answer will as clearly as the Question is, be based on  personal choice and style, which I thought SE Writing didn't welcome.

Let us look at what the different sentences mean, if we assume that neither the window nor the gaps have been mentioned before:

Sunlight entered through gaps in a boarded-up window.
Translation:
There are multiple windows. Sunlight enters through some but not necessarily all of the many gaps in only one of them.

Sunlight entered through gaps in the boarded-up window.
There is a single window. Sunlight enters through some but not necessarily all of the many gaps in this window.

Sunlight entered through the gaps in a boarded-up window.
There are multiple windows. Sunlight enters through all of the gaps in one of these windows.

Sunlight entered through the gaps in the boarded-up window.
There is a single window. Sunlight enters through all the gaps in this window.


Now let us look at what the different sentences mean, if we assume that both the window and the gaps have been mentioned before:

Sunlight entered through gaps in a boarded-up window.
There are multiple windows. Sunlight enters through some but not necessarily all of the many gaps in another window than the one mentioned before.

Sunlight entered through gaps in the boarded-up window.
Sunlight enters through some but not necessarily all of the many gaps in the window that was mentioned previously.

Sunlight entered through the gaps in a boarded-up window.
There are multiple windows. Sunlight enters through the previously specified gaps in another window than the one mentioned before.

Sunlight entered through the gaps in the boarded-up window.
Sunlight enters through the previously specified gaps in the window that was mentioned before.


Finally, let us look at what the different sentences mean, if we assume that the window, but not the gaps, have been mentioned before:

Sunlight entered through gaps in a boarded-up window.
There are multiple windows. Sunlight enters through some but not necessarily all of the many gaps in another window than the one mentioned before.

Sunlight entered through gaps in the boarded-up window.
Sunlight enters through some but not necessarily all of the many gaps in the window that was mentioned previously.

Sunlight entered through the gaps in a boarded-up window.
There are multiple windows. Sunlight enters through all of the gaps in another window than the one mentioned before.

Sunlight entered through the gaps in the boarded-up window.
Sunlight enters through all of the gaps in the window that was mentioned before.


What you want to say, I don't know.

An opinion is explicitly asked for so here is one. The balance between definite/indefinite is one with many interpretive possibilities and readers can have varied reactions to the nuances. In this case since we're talking about POV, what Jake notices may be a good way to analyse the difference.
I don't think that the second example needs to assume that the reader has previous knowledge of gaps in boarded up windows in this room because it just draws attention to the fact that Jake has just noticed the gaps (rather than, say, lines of bright light on the floor). Also, I doubt that the first example will lead many readers into speculations about other windows and how well they may be covered.
The most natural reaction would be the simplest one as I see it, and so the difference here is subtle, but it tells us more about what Jake sees than anything else. In that sense we have two levels of definiteness. Saying 'gaps' is noncommittal compared to saying 'a gap', 'the gaps' is also a bit more specific.
This may be compared to something like

A deep rumble emanated from a shaft on the left.
A deep rumble emanated from the shaft on the left.
The deep rumble... a shaft ...
The deep rumble... the shaft ...

We can certainly write "He grabbed a handle of a door" if he's panicked in a room with lots of doors and wasn't really choosing which to try first.
So the options are best chosen on what we want to tell the reader about the POV character's attention or state of mind.

I like this answer. I think there’s a lot of room for flexibility in narrative writing because, as you say, we’re trying to put the reader in the shoes of a character. This is very apparent in a lot of openings to a story, in which you may see something like: ‘Jake opened the door.’ The reader is expected to assume we’re talking about a particular door without any context.
